# dynamicaly creating file ,file path not working on server machine

Tags: php, canvas

I am saving canvas to a file. Code creates a png file in the upload folder. It is working correctly on local machine but when i try to run this on the server, I am not able to find the file in the upload folder. am i giving wrong path ?

After file creation i am printing alert, so i get file creation alert but file is not just created in the upload folder .

```
if ( isset($_POST["image"]) && !empty($_POST["image"]) ) { 

    // get the image data
    $data = $_POST['image'];

    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
    list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
    $data = base64_decode($data);

    //Image name
    $filename ="image". md5(uniqid()) . '.png';

    $file ='../upload/'.$filename;  

  // decode the image data and save it to file
    file_put_contents($file,$data);


}
```

Comment: maybe you don't have the right permissions on upload folder in your server. Have you checked that?

Comment: use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] & set your path to upload folder like this...$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/.*your path*./upload';

Answer (score 0):

make sure directory '../upload' exists or create it first